# Can we save an image into .doc file with AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am loading an external .jpg file into flash through AS3.0 with Loader class and later I need to save the image file into .doc with FileReference Class... Is it possible?

Please Help me...
Thanks a ton..

Comment: Do you want to add it to an existing .doc or make a new one containing just the image? Also is this a web-based application or an AIR desktop app?

Comment: You can create PDF's from Flash using PHP, not sure about .doc's though. See http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/. Hope this helps

Comment: @puggsoy I want to add the image to a new doc file....Its a desktop application....

Answer (score 0):

Wow... this is a good question!  Yes this is possible, but not all through Flash.

REQUIRED: Flash / PHP

How to (I'll add full examples later):

(1) create a php page that will accept the raw post output

(2) set the headers on the php page to match a .doc file

(3) send the image data from Flash to PHP, have php serve the .doc file back

What this will do is allow the user to send/save the image in Flash, and have a download context box popup to save the .doc file.

Comment: is it not possible with only Actionscript? Because I don't know how to program PHP.....

Comment: @user2006254 everything is possible with flash ;)  But this would be some-what difficult.  You would have to read the raw bytes and re-construct them based on .doc file requirements (not recommended).  If you really want to do this all in Flash, then a PDF as mentioned by Paul may be your best solution.